# Name not definded

Tags: python

I am having some problems with this function

I already unbugged the code and the function is running normaly. Actually, it looks that the problem is in the print, but i don't know what

```
def cond(par1,par2,par3,par4):
    sum=0
    t=[]
    for i in range(0,4):
        sum=sum+par1[i][1]/constantek[par1[i][0]]
    pcond=(par2-par3)*((par4)**(2))*(sum)**(-1)

    for i in range (0,5):
        t[0]=par2
        t[4]=par3
        t1=(par[i][1]*pcond)/(constantek[par1[i][0]]*(par4)**2)-t[i]
        t.append(t1)
    return(pcond,t)
print(pcond,t)

and the problem is: name 'pcond' is not defined
```

Comment: You're not calling your function or using the value returned from it.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
print(pcond, t = cond(par1, par2, par3, par4))
```

instead (you should of course define the 4 params first).

The problem is that the two variables are only defined in the function and therefor are local in the function and not available elsewhere. So as you print them python won't find them existing.

Comment: the problem is that i defined the 4 params before enter in the function:

Comment: There are inputs before enter in the function, that will receive those values that was gived in the inputs

Answer (score 1):

your code has 2 problems :

1-wrong indentation for your print statement.
2-You print after you return, which won't work.
Here's a reformat of what you're trying to do :

```
def cond(par1,par2,par3,par4):
    sum=0
    t=[]
    for i in range(0,4):
        sum=sum+par1[i][1]/constantek[par1[i][0]]
    pcond=(par2-par3)*((par4)**(2))*(sum)**(-1)

    for i in range (0,5):
        t[0]=par2
        t[4]=par3
        t1=(par[i][1]*pcond)/(constantek[par1[i][0]]*(par4)**2)-t[i]
        t.append(t1)
    print(pcond,t)
    return(pcond,t)
```